# Combine similar rows from CASE Statement in PG Admin PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I need help in my query. I have this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT("Fruits"), "Apple", "Orange", "Grapes", 
(SELECT (CASE WHEN "Apple" = TRUE 
         AND (("Orange" = TRUE OR "Orange" = FALSE OR "Orange" is NULL )
              OR ("Grapes" = TRUE OR "Grapes" = FALSE OR "Grapes" is NULL)) THEN ('1')
 ELSE (0)
 END) as "Market A"),
 (SELECT (CASE WHEN ("Apple" = FALSE OR "Apple" is NULL)
         AND (("Orange" = TRUE)
              AND ("Grapes" = FALSE OR "Grapes" is NULL)) THEN ('1')
 ELSE (0)
 END) as "Market B"),
 (SELECT (CASE WHEN ("Apple" = FALSE OR "Apple" is NULL)
         AND (("Orange" = TRUE)
              AND ("Grapes" = TRUE )) THEN ('1')
 ELSE (0)
 END) as "Market C")
 FROM market
      WHERE "Fresh" = TRUE
      GROUP BY "Fruits", "Apple", "Orange", "Grapes"
```

This is the result that I am having

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Market   | Apple | Orange | Grapes | Market A | Market B | Market C |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Basket A | true  | true   | true   |    1     |    0     |    0     |
Basket A | true  | true   | null   |    1     |    0     |    0     |
Basket B | null  | null   | null   |    0     |    0     |    0     |
Basket A | true  | null   | null   |    1     |    0     |    0     |
Basket A | null  | true   | null   |    0     |    1     |    0     |
Basket C | null  | true   | null   |    0     |    1     |    0     |
```

I want a result that is in the table below. Asking for help on how can I combine the similar rows and count them? Thank you very much for the help and really appreciate it. Just a newbie in making some queries.

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
Market   | Market A | Market B | Market C |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Basket A |    3     |    0     |    0     |
Basket A |    0     |    1     |    0     |
Basket C |    0     |    1     |    0     |
```

Comment: Note that `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`. And `distinct` combined with `group by` hardly ever makes sense

Comment: Where does the column `market` come from? It is not part of your SELECT statement

Comment: thank you for this. should i just change my logic to combine similar rows?

Comment: market is a table that I am using. the columns are "Fruits", "Apple", "Orange", "Grapes"

Comment: But your desired output contains a **column** labelled `market` (with the contents `Basket A`, `Basket B` and `Basket C`)  where does that come from?

Comment: they are the datas from my table with a condition FRESH = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for conditional  aggregation:

```
select m.market, -- not sure where this comes from
       count(*) filter (where "Apple" = true) as "Market A",
       count(*) filter (where coalesce("Apple", false) = false 
                          and "Orange" 
                          and coalesce("Grape", false) = false) as "Market B",
       count(*) filter (where coalesce("Apple", false) = false 
                          and "Orange" = true
                          and "Grapes" = true) as "Market C"
from market m
where "Fresh" = true
group by m.market;
```

Note that I removed the conditions `("Orange" = TRUE OR "Orange" = FALSE OR "Orange" is NULL )` and `("Grapes" = TRUE OR "Grapes" = FALSE OR "Grapes" is NULL)` as both are always true and will not change the outcome of your condition.

It's unclear to me if the column `market` in your desired output is a column of the table are not.

Comment: Also note that the use of quoted identifiers is generally [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names)